# How do you clean up textures that are too photo-realistic to match the rest of your game assets?

Tags: textures, assets

I was browsing for textures online and notice most of it are too photo-realistic and many of them is just photo of real thing.
I'm sure there some "cleanup" process for this type of texture using Photoshop filter or via other tool etc.
Let say I want texture to match Left for Dead 2 look.
Does anyone have any links\resources on this?

Comment: Sorry to be the one to break the news, but if you want a consistent look throughout your entire game, you're going to have to make your own textures. If it is a seriously developed game, you should have the resources to do that; if it is not, then it shouldn't really matter.

Comment: Yes it's called a graphics artist I believe ^^

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there are filters you can apply. Though it will depend on the style you're looking for. For example using GIMP I produced this:

[image]

From photo realistic to gritty semi-realistic cartoon. The filters I applied:

1. Apply RGB noise
2. Apply Blur
3. Apply Cartoon

Very quick to do. But you may have to tweak it more depending on the style you're after.

Original image [source](http://face2face.si.edu/my_weblog/2008/12/portrait-of-barack-obama-by-martin-schoeller.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can always cut the number of pixels to 90% "make the picture thiner"

If you get rid of 1,9 mb from a 2mb picture you will get your pic as sharp as the Pokemons :) I Hope that that is what you meant.